# composing a quicksort using input and output arrays in python

Tags: python

I'm struggling to create my quicksort algorithm for my algorithms class. Here is what I have thus far. It's not incredibly succinct, but I want to know how to make what I have work if possible to better understand my own code. My base case `if` statements at the top don't seem to be breaking recursion the way I want to.

```
def quicksort(array_in):
    """Quicksort algorithm."""

    if len(array_in) == 0: #If array is empty
        return 

    if len(array_in) == 1: #If array is only one element
        return array_in

    if len(array_in) == 2:
        if array_in[0] < array_in[1]:
            return [array_in[0], array_in[1]]
        return [array_in[1], array_in[0]]

    array_out = []
    pivot = array_in[len(array_in) // 2]

    # Generate sub arrays.
    sub_smaller = []
    sub_bigger = []
    for i in array_in:
        if i < pivot:
            sub_smaller.append(i)
        else:
            sub_bigger.append(i)

    sub_smaller = quicksort(sub_smaller)
    sub_bigger = quicksort(sub_bigger)

    for i in sub_smaller:
        array_out.append(i)

    for i in sub_bigger:
        array_out.append(i)

    return array_out
```

Comment: One problem I see is that in case of a single item in input array, the return value is this item while it should be a list containing only the item.

Comment: "My base case if statements at the top don't seem to be breaking recursion the way I want to." How so?

Comment: @MarkSnyder, the base cases aren't breaking recursion at all.

Comment: Would you mind providing some input cases where they're not working? Because your code typically does work for me, although it broke with the input `[6,5,4,-1,-2,-.5,3,2,1]`. But it does work for `[-2,-1,5,4,3,-.5,0,1,2]`, `[-1.0,2]`, and several other variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you include `pivot` in `sub_bigger`. This means that if `pivot` is ever the lowest number in `array_in` and `len(array_in) > 2`, you'll get stuck infinitely trying to sort `array_in`. You also need to return an empty array if `array_in` is empty, or the return value will be `None` and therefore non-iterable. This should work for you, although I made no effort to optimize it:

```
def quicksort(array_in):
    """Quicksort algorithm."""

    if len(array_in) <= 1: #If array is empty or only one element
        return array_in

    if len(array_in) == 2:
        if array_in[0] < array_in[1]:
            return [array_in[0], array_in[1]]
        return [array_in[1], array_in[0]]

    array_out = []
    pivot_idx = len(array_in) // 2

    # Generate sub arrays.
    sub_smaller = []
    sub_bigger = []
    for idx,val in enumerate(array_in):
        if idx == pivot_idx:
            continue
        if val < array_in[pivot_idx]:
            sub_smaller.append(val)
        else:
            sub_bigger.append(val)

    sub_smaller = quicksort(sub_smaller)
    sub_bigger = quicksort(sub_bigger)

    for i in sub_smaller:
        array_out.append(i)

    array_out.append(array_in[pivot_idx])

    for i in sub_bigger:
        array_out.append(i)

    return array_out
```